# libusb endpoint direction printer

Tags: linux, endpoint, libusb

I want to address directly a USB device (a receipts printer) using libusb-1.0 library. I've managed to do it with another printer (also for printing receipts, but another brand), but the one I try now presents a new problem: it has two endpoints, both in the IN direction (device -> host), so I don't know how to send the data to the printer!

This is what gives me lsusb -v (sorry it's a bit long):

```
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 04b3:4535 IBM Corp. 4610 Suremark Printer
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04b3 IBM Corp.
  idProduct          0x4535 4610 Suremark Printer
  bcdDevice            2.16
  iManufacturer           1 (c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2000
  iProduct                2 IBM Retail USB 4610 SureMark Printer
  iSerial                 3 NO SERIAL NUMBER
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x40
      (Missing must-be-set bit!)
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              4 Firmware Upgrade Interface (Usage = A000h, Usage Page = FF45h)
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      53
          Report Descriptor: (length is 53)
            Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x45 0xff ] 65349
                            (null)
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x00 0xa0 ] 40960
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Application
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x07 0x01 ] 263
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 0xa0 ] 40961
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x02 0xa0 ] 40962
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x03 0xa0 ] 40963
                            (null)
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x05 0x01 ] 261
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Main  ): Feature, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              5 Printer Interface (Usage = 3500h, Usage Page = FF45h)
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
          Report Descriptor: (length is 71)
            Item(Global): Usage Page, data= [ 0x45 0xff ] 65349
                            (null)
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x00 0x35 ] 13568
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Collection, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
                            Application
            Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x01 ] 1
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0xfe 0x03 ] 1022
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x01 0x35 ] 13569
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x0f ] 15
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x02 0x35 ] 13570
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Input, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0x00 0x01 ] 256
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x03 0x35 ] 13571
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Feature, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Global): Report ID, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
            Item(Global): Report Size, data= [ 0x08 ] 8
            Item(Global): Report Count, data= [ 0xfe ] 254
            Item(Global): Logical Minimum, data= [ 0x00 ] 0
            Item(Global): Logical Maximum, data= [ 0xff 0x00 ] 255
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x11 0x35 ] 13585
                            (null)
            Item(Main  ): Output, data= [ 0x02 ] 2
                            Data Variable Absolute No_Wrap Linear
                            Preferred_State No_Null_Position Non_Volatile Bitfield
            Item(Main  ): End Collection, data=none
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               4
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

If I read correctly, we can see that there are 2 interfaces (line 21), an endpoint for each interface (lines 33 and 96) but each is the type IN (lines 84 and 158) thus operating in the device-to-host direction so I really don't know how to send any data to the printer :-(

Comment: Have you tried sending data via control transfer on endpoint 0x00?

Comment: No I did not because I have no idea what to put for the bmRequestType and bRequest parameters.
I also tried to use the hidapi library, but unsuccesfully... :(

Comment: For figuring out which data to send you should use an usb sniffer with the original driver.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `iInterface` fields: the first interface is *Firmware Upgrade Interface* and the second one is *Printer Interface*.

Comment: I agree with that, but the correponding endpoint operate in the wrong direction, no ? Line 158 : bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN